# Update gitlab ci to use latest docker and latest aws cli

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, aws-cli

I have a gitlab pipeline that uses docker and awscli

at the moment is like this:

```
image: docker:19.03.5
services:
  - docker:19.03.5-dind



stages:
  - Build
  - Push

before_script:
  - apk add python3
  - pip3 install awscli
  - docker load --input data/image.tar
  - $(aws ecr get-login --no-include-email --region us-east-1)
```

The build phase pulls docker:19.03.5 and install awscli-1.20.55.

I am trying to use the latest docker:20.10.9 and awscli2 without success.
If I change the yml to pull docker 20.10.9 it will fail when calling `pip3 install awcli`

I also tried installing curl and then using the suggested method for linux without success. I still get error at that step.

any clues how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you compare the output of the pipeline with the two docker versions you see that a different python version is used with each.

`python3 (3.8.10-r0)` with `docker:19.03.5` and
`python3 (3.9.5-r1)` with `docker:20.10.9`

With `python3 (3.9.5-r1)` there is no `pip3` included so you need to manually add it before you install awscli.

```
  before_script:
    - apk add python3
    - apk add py3-pip
    - pip3 install awscli
```